# StandardTokenizer behaviour

Tags: java, search, lucene, tokenize

Given the code is running under Lucene 3.0.1

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.*;
import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;

public class MyAnalyzer extends Analyzer {

   public TokenStream tokenStream(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
       return
               new StopFilter(
                       true,
                       new StandardTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_30, reader),
                       StopAnalyzer.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS_SET
               );
   }

   private static void printTokens(String string) throws IOException {
       TokenStream ts = new MyAnalyzer().tokenStream("default", new
StringReader(string));
       TermAttribute termAtt = ts.getAttribute(TermAttribute.class);
       while(ts.incrementToken()) {
           System.out.print(termAtt.term());
           System.out.print(" ");
       }
       System.out.println();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       printTokens("one_two_three");           // prints "one two three"
       printTokens("four4_five5_six6");        // prints "four4_five5_six6"
       printTokens("seven7_eight_nine");       // prints "seven7_eight nine"
       printTokens("ten_eleven11_twelve");     // prints "ten_eleven11_twelve"
   }
}
```

I can understand why `one_two_three` and `four4_five5_six6` are tokenized as they are, as this is explained in the [StandardTokenizer class header Javadoc](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardTokenizer.html). But the other two cases are more subtle and I'm
not quite sure I get the idea.

**Q1:** If appearance of `7` after `seven` makes it joint token with `eight`
but separate to `nine`, why is `ten` glued to `eleven11`?

**Q2:** Is there any standard and/or easy way to make `StandardTokenizer` always
split on the underscore?

Answer (score 3):

That's an interesting find. I'm not exactly sure how to explain why it's doing that for Q1. I can however provide code to split on the remaining underscores for Q2:

```
public class MyAnalyzer extends Analyzer {
    public TokenStream tokenStream(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
        StandardTokenizer tokenizer = new StandardTokenizer(
                Version.LUCENE_30, reader);
        TokenStream tokenStream = new StandardFilter(tokenizer);
        tokenStream = new MyTokenFilter(tokenStream);
        tokenStream = new StopFilter(true, tokenStream,
                StopAnalyzer.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS_SET);
        return tokenStream;
    }
}

public class MyTokenFilter extends TokenFilter {
    private final TermAttribute termAttr;
    private String[] terms;
    private int pos;

    public MyTokenFilter(TokenStream tokenStream) {
        super(tokenStream);
        this.termAttr = input.addAttribute(TermAttribute.class);
    }

    public boolean incrementToken() throws IOException {
        if (terms == null) {
            if (!input.incrementToken()) {
                return false;
            }
            terms = termAttr.term().split("_");
        }

        termAttr.setTermBuffer(terms[pos++]);
        if (pos == terms.length) {
            terms = null;
            pos = 0;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: but doing so i think that the terms will have wrong start offset and end offset atributes, isn't it?